# What is the feature with I can prevent users from accessing certain content in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm quite new to spring security and I don't know how to search for this kind of functionality. My problem is. I authenticate the user with spring security. Lets say with form based auth. So the user is logged in. He can navigate through the app. Let's say we have a webapp that stores transactions in a db, and retrieves them by id. If we wanna see the transaction detail we send a request with the transaction id. So for example /transaciontapp/gettransaction?id=134. In the previous page the app only loaded the transaction that belonged to that particular user. But now I can edit the link to any id, and with a get method, being a logged in user I can see transaction that I'm not supposed to. So in spring security, how can I handle that, to restrict certain content to certain users?

Answer (score 1):

I want to suggest you to read the [official Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/reference/htmlsingle/) to get an overall idea first, what Spring Security is about.

A starting point is simply adding it to your project, e.g. using Gradle by adding the dependency `compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')`. The next step is creating a configuration class for it. This contains how authentication should work for your project.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // your rules
}
```

Those rules define how to approach topics like

- Technically: e.g. HTTP Basic Auth, Token based, Cookie based, Form based
- Where are credentials stored: in-memory, custom UserDetailService implementation
- Adding filters for HTTP requests
- Settings for session management
- Rules for different routes; What to protect how? Anonymous login? Roles?
- Security concerns like Cross Site Request Forgery or Cross Origin Request Strategy

Please read the documentation and see a lot of other Stack Overflow questions regarding Spring Security before asking such a basic one.